# Are all python magic methods available to all objects

Tags: python

Am I correct in assuming that an object in Python has a default implementation of all magic methods (the ones surrounded by the double underscore, such as `__init__`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

```
>>> object.__add__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__add__'
```

Some of them do have default implementations, like `__init__`, but most of them don't.

Comment: @wobbily_col: Generally, special methods are methods that Python uses to implement language features. For example, `__iter__` for iteration, `__add__` for addition, and `__init__` for object initialization. Having a default implementation has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

No it does not have default implementations of all the magic functions.

It would be only true if all the objects were inherited from a common default base class.

There are different classes and different implementation of these classes require different magic functions.

Do `object.__class__` to get the class name

To find out all the functions in that object you can do `dir(object)`

More - http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html

Comment: "It would be only true if all the objects were inherited from a common default base class." - except, they *do* all inherit from a common default base class. That class is `object`.